# How to use HasComputedColumnSql across relationship in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use [computed properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations) to calculate an aggregated value in below example

```
public class Team 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public double Contribution { get; set; }  // team's aggregated contribution in hours
}

public class Member 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public double IndividualContribution { get; set; } // member's contribution in hours
}

public class TeamContext : DBContext 
{
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder Builder)  
    {
        Builder.Entity<Member>().HasOne(_=>_.Team).WithMany(_=>_.Members);
        Builder.Entity<Team>().Property(_=>_.Contribution).HasComputedColumnSql("SELECT SUM([M].[IndividualContribution]) FROM [Member] AS [M] WHERE [M].[TeamId] = [Id]");
    }
}
```

But when I try to apply the migration, I get this error:

```
ALTER TABLE [Member] ADD [Contribution] AS SELECT SUM([M].[IndividualContribution]) FROM [Member] AS [M] WHERE [M].[TeamId] = [Id];
```

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: HasComputedColumnSql can't be configured using SELECT queries, or using other entities.

Comment: The direct reason for the exception is that the SELECT statement should be enclosed in parentheses. But if you do that you'll get "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

Answer (score 2):

HasComputedColumnSql can't be configured using SELECT queries, or using other entities. You may use entity function such as following to update team contribution and call it when you want to update team contribution.

```
public class Team {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List < Member > Members { get; set; }
  public double Contribution { get; set; } // team's aggregated contribution in hours

  public void UpdateTeamContribution() {
    Contribution = Members.Sum(m =>m.IndividualContribution);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't intend to store the Contribution, I want the it to be computed every time a Team is fetched from the database.

Comment: In that case you can use a NotMapped property and compute the value.
e.g.
 [NotMapped]
  public double Contribution
  {
    get { return Members.Sum(m =>m.IndividualContribution); }
  }

Comment: Actually, initially I tried this  
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
  public decimal Contribution {
    get => Members.Sum(_ => _.IndividualContribution);
    private set { }
  }
  
But I was getting below error
  
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)